# sum column values in a row and save into another column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add together the values in separate columns in a row and save the result in another column within that same row. I want this for each row in the table.

```
Insert into DataTable (Total) values 
((select (T1+T2+T3+T4+T5) from DataTable))
```

I get an error message:

> Subquery returned more than one value.

I can guess that my Select statement returns multiple values and is then attempting to store the values returned into a single row in the table.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
UPDATE DataTable
SET Total = T1+T2+T3+T4+T5
```

However, you can get the server to calculate this automatically using a `computed column`. Remove the `Total` column and add the replacement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE DataTable DROP COLUMN Total

ALTER TABLE DataTable ADD Total as (T1+T2+T3+T4+T5)
```

Comment: You'll have to provide a data type for the column as well.

Comment: @NickyvV No you don't. The data type is inferred from the formula provided.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate (Total) column will already have to exist:

```
UPDATE DataTable
SET Total = field1 + field2 + field3 + field4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE DataTable
SET Total = T1+T2+T3+T4+T5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the value into a column in the same row then you need to do something like

```
UPDATE DataTable SET Total = T1 + T2
```

But if you want Total to always be the sum of other columns you should make it a computed column.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx